# Spread props type in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I was creating a react component for icon.

The component looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import MIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
import MaterialIconCommunity from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";
import icons from "./names";

interface Props { 
  name: string
}
const Icon = ({ name, ...props }: Props) => {
  if (icons[name] === "material-community") {
    return <MaterialIconCommunity name={name} {...props} />;
  }
  if (icons[name] === "material") {
    return <MIcon name={name} {...props} />;
  }
```

What should be the type of `...props` here?

Answer (score 1):

You are extending a component from a library. If that library provides types, you should be able to use them and extend with your additional props (in this case, just "name"). You should inspect the source file for `MaterialIconCommunity` and `MIcon`, but it would look something like this:

```
interface Props extends SomeMaterialIconPropsType { 
  name: string
}
```